# Stacking GBT using Logistic Regression

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, stacking

1) I build Gradient Boosted Tree Model in h2o and now i have the POJO. 
2) I extracted the weight for each tree of GBT for my population 
3) I used the extracted weight to train a logistic regression model.

What do you think about this stacking approach ? Have anyone worked on this before ? Any leads will be appreciated ?

Comment: This is awfully broad, & may not be answerable here. Can you make this narrower & more concrete than 'what do you think...'?

Comment: Never heard about it. The number of weight is the tree numbers, how to train a logistic regression with this little samples.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_feature_transformation.html#example-ensemble-plot-feature-transformation-py) on scikit-learn, a
[paper](https://research.facebook.com/publications/practical-lessons-from-predicting-clicks-on-ads-at-facebook/) on Facebook, and a [topic](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-people-use-gradient-boosted-decision-trees-to-do-feature-transform) on Quora, all discussing this approach.

Basically, you tend to get slightly better performance, because you are combining predictors with different inherent biases. This approach also allows for online learning, since you can cache the computationally demanding gradient boosting part and update only the logistic regression part.

One important thing to keep in mind is that you have to use different subsets of the data for training gradient boosting and for training logistic regression (see the scikit-learn link for an example). Whether the slight increase in performance is worth the added complexity depends on the particular application.